# How to Solve the List index out of bounds: 0 issue

Tags: apex, exception

How can I solve the List index out of bounds: 0  issue .

```
ID Accid;
  Account[] acc = [Select id,name from account where name ='test']; -->1
  if(acc.size() >0){
     Accid = acc[0].id;
   }else {
    Account[] acc1 =[Select id,name from Account where name = 'test 1'];-->2
    if(acc1.size()>0){
       Accid = acc1[0].id;
     }
   }

  User[] u = [Select id,Name from User Where Accountid=:Accid];-->3 
  if(u.size() >0){ //here throw the error like List index out of bounds: 0
    //some logic here
    //
   }

 ----some code---------
 --- some code-----------
 --- some code----------
```

Here i got issue that is 1 query executed then 3 query executed size 0 after iI am not get any error executed next lines that's work fine. but 2 query executed then 3 query executed size 0 now next lines not executed that's throw the error like List index out of bounds: 0

Thanks

Comment: Kittu: Please update your original question instead of this duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In all probability it is occuring where youre trying to access the value by index and your soql query is unable to find any matching records.

The size() method on a null would throw a null pointer exception rather than an index out of bounds so I'm guessing the code in braces tries to access u[0]

You can add a not null check to each of your if statements or alternatively use the native isEmpty method, eg

```
If(u!=null && u.size() > 0)
```

Or alternatively

```
If(!u.isEmpty())
```

Comment: hi techtrekker thanks for your response .. but i used what you said that is not working still i am facing same problem...